# Converting video to base64 gives "out of memory error"

Tags: android, string, video, base64, encode

When I convert small videos, it does not give an error. But when I am converting bigger videos, it gives the error below.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.util.Base64.encode(Base64.java:534)
at android.util.Base64.encode(Base64.java:494)
at android.util.Base64.encodeToString(Base64.java:456)
at gcm.b4deploy.com.operations2.StartedTasksAdapter.videoToBase64(StartedTasksAdapter.java:402)
at gcm.b4deploy.com.operations2.StartedTasksAdapter.access$200(StartedTasksAdapter.java:57)
gcm.b4deploy.com.operations2.StartedTasksAdapter$2$1.fileSelected(StartedTasksAdapter.java:288)
at gcm.b4deploy.com.operations2.FileChooser$1.onItemClick(FileChooser.java:57)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1114)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2937)
at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3695)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5037)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And following is my videoToBase64 method;

```
private String videoToBase64(File file) {
    String encodedString = null;

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    byte[] bytes;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bytes = output.toByteArray();
    **encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);**//error is in this line
    Log.i("Strng", encodedString);

    return encodedString;
}
```

I have read some questions about this which are saying that I should split video and encode part by part but I dont understand how to do it.

And is there any idea about what is the bound size of video to be able to not to get this outOfMemoryError?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add this tag in Application menifest file under "application" tag:

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

Actually android:largeHeap is the instrument for increasing your allocated memory to app.

Answer (score 1):

The memory is an issue in android. You should split the video in few parts, encode each part, send it and recombine it on destination.